# #TempTable in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm just inserting some values into `#TempTable` (which is not defined) by using `SELECT INTO` from a function within a stored procedure. But can see the `#TempTable` being created in temporary tables drop down list in the database.

Moreover is there any difference between already defines `#TempTable` with some attributes and Just using `INSERT INTO #TempTable` without defining it. Same query when I run outside of the stored procedure it creates a `#tempTable`.

```
ALTER PROEDURE SpBorBySec 
    (@sec NVARCHAR(30))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM FnFoBoSec(@sec)

    SELECT 
        BorrowerID, Borrowerfname, SUM(fine) AS Total_fine, 
        COUNT(BorrowerID) AS Total_Loan 
    INTO
        #BorrowerSummary   
    FROM
        FnFoBoSec(@sec) 
    GROUP BY
        BorrowerID, BorrowerFName

    SELECT * FROM #BorrowerSummary
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Same query when i run outside of Stored Procedure it creates a #tempTable.

The temp table is created in the stored procedure, but temp tables created in a stored procedure are automatically dropped at the end of the stored procedure.